# SSIS - Passing a resultset to foreachloop to data flow task

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, foreach-loop-container

I have an execute SQL task which is generating a result which I am storing in a variable

[Result Set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHcpy.png)

then I am moving it into foreach loop
[Foreeachloop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHcpy.png)

Now what I am trying to do is the

result I got in Execute SQL task should be loaded into a table and I am using Data flow task for that in the foreach loop as there around 20 odd sever it will execute on.

Thanks

(This follows on from this question: [How to pass table variable data into a data flow in ssis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35735332/how-to-pass-table-variable-data-into-a-data-flow-in-ssis))

Comment: are you trying to cycle around different servers, get drive space on each server then save that in to a central table? It really helps to have background.

Comment: So are you getting an error?   Stating what you want to do isn't a question.   What is your question?